# Whats the difference between two multiple user input programs?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner dd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String b = dd.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter num");
    int num = dd.nextInt();
  }
}
```

And

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner dd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter num");
        int num = dd.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter name");
        String b = dd.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Why the latter doesn't work peoperly(doesn't let me enter name), while the first one does?

I have made up a new version without that annoying "Scanner scan = new Scanner".
And what about this solution? What cons may it have?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Enter num");
    int i = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String b = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should use nextLine() all times and cast the value to the proper type

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, `nextInt()` does not scan over the newline character that the user inputs when pressing the Return key.

In the first case, `nextLine()` is encountered first so the problem doesn't manifest itself.

The moral of the story is to *always* use `nextLine()` and parse the resulting string accordingly. Use something like `Integer#parseInt` to convert a string to an integer.

Comment: It says "String cannot be converted to int"

Comment: Of course it will. See my last new sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The second program expects an Int first and then a name. And hence might be erroring out when a name is entered.